# Page Refresh Only After Page Is Validated

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, page-refresh

Hi I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I've put together [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/chris/test.php) page which has working 'client' and 'server' side validation.

What I'm now trying to do is add a page refresh and 'scroll to top', once the page has passed validation.

To the script used in the first link I've added the following code to try and invoke this functionality:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').fadeOut(400, function() {
        location.reload();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('body').fadeIn(400);
        }, 500);
        window.scrollTo(x - coord, y - coord);
    });
}, 2000);
```

The problem I'm having, is that irrespective of whether the the form passes validation, the page refreshes as can be seen in [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/chris/test2.php) page. So the full JavaScript code looks like this:

**Post Update - Through working with @rahul, I've now have a working solution as below. NB I only needed to change the JavaScript code**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("#addlocation").validationEngine();
            $("#addlocation").bind("jqv.field.result", function(event, field, errorFound, prompText){ console.log(errorFound) })
        });
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addlocation').submit(function(){

        //check the form is not currently submitting
        if($(this).data('formstatus') !== 'submitting'){

            //setup variables
            var form = $(this),
                formData = form.serialize(),
                formUrl = form.attr('action'),
                formMethod = form.attr('method'), 
                responseMsg = $('#saverecordresponse');

            //add status data to form
            form.data('formstatus','submitting');

            //show response message - waiting
            responseMsg.hide()
                       .addClass('response-waiting')
                       .text('Please Wait...')
                       .fadeIn(200);

            //send data to server for validation
            $.ajax({
                url: formUrl,
                type: formMethod,
                data: formData,
                success:function(data){

                    //setup variables
                    var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data), 
                        klass = '';

                    //response conditional
                    switch(responseData.status){
                        case 'error':
                            klass = 'response-error';
                        break;
                        case 'success':
                            klass = 'response-success';
                        break;  
                    }

                    //show reponse message
                    responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){
                        $(this).removeClass('response-waiting')
                               .addClass(klass)
                               .text(responseData.message)
                               .fadeIn(200,function(){
                                   //set timeout to hide response message
                                   setTimeout(function(){
                                       responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){
                                           $(this).removeClass(klass);
                                           form.data('formstatus','idle');
                                       });
                                   },3000)
                                   if (klass=='response-success')
                               {
                                   setTimeout(function () {
                                   $('body').fadeOut(400, function () {
                                       location.reload();
                                       setTimeout(function () {
                                           $('body').fadeIn(400);
                                       }, 500);
                                       window.scrollTo(x - coord, y - coord);
                                   });
                               }, 2000);
                               }
                                });
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        //prevent form from submitting
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

and this is a cut down version (I've deleted most of the validation rules for preview purposes) the PHP code which works in conjunction with the JavaScript and saves the record to a MySQL database.

```
<?php


    //sanitize data
    $userid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userid']);   
    $locationname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['locationname']);   
    $returnedaddress = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['returnedaddress']); 

    if(empty($locationname)){
        $status = "error";
        $message = "You need to enter a name for this location!";
    }

    else{
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (userid, locationname, returnedaddress) VALUES ('$userid', '$locationname', '$returnedaddress')");  
            if($query){ //if insert is successful
                $status = "success";
                $message = "Location Saved!";   
            }
            else { //if insert fails
                $status = "error";
                $message = "I'm sorry, there has been a technical error!";  
            }

    }

    //return json response
    $data = array(
        'status' => $status,
        'message' => $message
    );

    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
?>
```

I must admit, I'm not sure where the problem lies, but I'm the first to admit I'm a little new to JavaScript and jQuery.

I just wondered whether someone may be able to look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong, or even perhaps suggest a better alternative to make the page refresh once the form passes validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily get it done using `return false`

check if validation not passed `return false`

```
if(Yourvalidation!=true)
{
return false;
}
```

after this section

```
 //response conditional
                    switch(responseData.status){
                        case 'error':
                            klass = 'response-error';
                        break;
                        case 'success':
                            klass = 'response-success';
                        break;  
                    }
```

check value of klass like this

```
    responseMsg.fadeOut(200, function () {
                            $(this).removeClass('response-waiting')
                           .addClass(klass)
                           .text(responseData.message)
                           .fadeIn(200, function () {
                               //set timeout to hide response message
                               setTimeout(function () {
                                   responseMsg.fadeOut(200, function () {
                                       $(this).removeClass(klass);
                                       form.data('formstatus', 'idle');
                                   });
                               }, 3000)
                               if (klass=='response-success')
                               {
                                   setTimeout(function () {
                                   $('body').fadeOut(400, function () {
                                       location.reload();
                                       setTimeout(function () {
                                           $('body').fadeIn(400);
                                       }, 500);
                                       window.scrollTo(x - coord, y - coord);
                                   });
                               }, 2000);
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   return false;  //use return false in else condition 
                               }
                           });
                        });
```

Comment: Hi @rahul, firstly, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. Secondly, my apologies, I'm a little new to this, but could you possibly explain where I would need to put this in my code please. I am already using a 'return false' statement so I'm not sure whether this is in addition to to the one I already have. I've added the full piece of script which creates the jQuery messages and page refresh to my original post if it helps. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: can you show me your js code where you are validating your form

Comment: HI @rahul, I've now added the JavaScript to my original post. Thank you and kind regards

Comment: Hi @rahul, thank you very much for this. Again, I offer my apologies because I forgot to include some code which I initially didn't think would affect the answer, I'm sorry! In conjunction with the JavaScript code I posted, the actual 'Message Text' comes form the PHP file which performs the 'server' side validation, and saves the record to a mySQL database. I've now added this to my original post. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: i just want to know that is klass returning correct status message or not if yes my solutions will work for you

Comment: Hi @rahul, thank you for your continued help with this. I've amended my code with your suggestion. Although the page doesn't refresh, which is great, the error message no longer appears at the bottom of the form. I've updated the second link in my original post to illustrate this. Many thanks and kind regards.

Comment: if it's not refreshing what is the problem now

Comment: Hi rahul, the jQuery error message which appears at the bottom of the page when the form fails 'server' side validation is no longer displayed to the user. If you could possibly please select the first link in my original post, then click the save button, this will display the message I'm referring to. I hope this helps. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: i have updated my code @IRHM one more time please check it now and please let me know

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16503/discussion-between-rahul-and-irhm)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `client` and `server` side validation by using this

```
if(Page_ClientValidate()) 
          return true;
    else 
          return false;
```

Comment: Hi @deepak, thank you very much for replying to my post. I've done some further work on this and I've now been able to put together a working solution as shown in my original post. Kind regards